# Trouble running Puppeteer in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I cant seem to get Puppeteer working properly when deployed to Firebase Cloud Functions.

**Puppeteer**: I can't upload my project when using Puppeteer, because I am uploading the Puppeteer-version of Chrome in my "functions" folder and it then exceeds the allowed size limit. Is this an appropriate road to go down, and can I circumvent the size restriction?

**Puppeteer-core**: I can't find an appropriate Chrome browser to use with it. "Chrome-aws-lambda" seems to not work with the latest version of Puppeteer-core. Maybe someone in here knows of an updated alternative?

Or maybe there is a solution that I don't know about?

I tried allocating more memory to my function (Increased from 256 mb to 1 gb), but it did not help. I also tried adding the "No sandbox" flag to Puppeteer, but that didn't help.
I have made sure that the downloaded version of Chrome by Puppeteer is located in my "functions" directory. This version of Chrome seems to be too big to upload to Firebase Cloud Functions though.
I also tried adding the new headless mode for Chrome to the code, but did not work.

This is my current code for Puppeteer browser:

```js
browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
            headless: "new",
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
        });
```

This is my code to inrease memory to 1 gb:

```js
exports.scheduledFunction = functions
    .runWith({ memory: '1GB' })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest downgrading your puppeteer version. Some of the newer versions have issues when used with Cloud Functions. You do not need to include Chrome in your functions folder.

I am using Puppeteer 16.2.0 in a Cloud Function with 4GB memory and it works fine for me. This is my code:

```
async function get_browser() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
  });

  return browser;
}
```

Parent function that calls get_browser is initialized with:

```
exports.functionName = functions.runWith({memory: "4GB", timeoutSeconds: 540}).https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
```

(Long timeout time is because the function performs multiple actions, and I was being cautious)